# cannot copy throught nio2 java copy function

Tags: java

1.Hello 
What i really meant is that when i run this program i get an unknown file named'mm' in the desktop.The program is not working in the way which i wanted.i want to copy 'oo.txt' from 'nn' folder to 'mm' folder

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
import java.io.*;


public class ListOfNumbers {


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Path p1 = Paths.get("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\nn\\oo.txt");
        Path p2 = Paths.get("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\mm");
        try{
            Files.copy(p1,p2,REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println("ff");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your description of your problem is so poor that after reading your text 3 times I still have no idea what your problem is.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "UnExpected Results" ? Can you please edit the question to mention what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Sorry for my poor description

Comment: Sorry for my poor description.What i really meant was that when i run this program i got an unknown file named'mm' in the desktop.The program is not working in the way which i wanted.i want to copy 'oo.txt' from 'nn' folder to 'mm' folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is the problem line

```
Path p2 = Paths.get("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\mm");
```

I guess you are trying to copy the file with the same name to "mm" folder. If this is the case then you need to specify the name of the file. What is happening is that the file copy function is copying the file as "mm" on your Desktop folder. To verify open your file in NotePad and see the contents..

Just change the line as

```
    Path p2 = Paths.get("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\mm\\oo.txt");
```

and you should be fine.